# Backendless + realm - storing arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm, backendless

I am new in backendless.com & Realm.io

I need to make a simple table with categories and few items that belong to categories

I have a problem with getting data from backendless, because i make class that must be compatible with backendless and Realm the same time

The problem is getting array from backendless:

```
class Category: Object {
dynamic var objectId = ""
dynamic var name = ""
dynamic var listNumber = 0
dynamic var imageName = ""
dynamic var image: NSData? = nil
dynamic var created: NSDate?
dynamic var updated: NSDate?
var dishes = List<Dish>() // <- my problem
```

Problem with 'dishes'.

Backendless manual says that i should do like this

https://backendless.com/feature-16-data-retrieval-api-how-to-load-objects-from-an-mbaas-storage/

```
var locations : [Location] = []
```

but Realm says that it not supports NSArray, and will work with List Format,

```
dynamic var dishes: [Dish] = [] // Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: ''NSArray' is not supported as an RLMObject property. All properties must be primitives, NSString, NSDate, NSData, RLMArray, or subclasses of RLMObject. See https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMObject.html for more information.'
```

And when i get array from backendless using  List , description of array looks like:

```
▿ [1] : Category {
objectId = 52E0D354-F1B1-2F64-FFD8-B4129ED0DA00;
name = Паста;
listNumber = 2;
imageName = pasta.png;
image = <(null) — 0 total bytes>;
created = 2016-03-12 17:07:35 +0000;
updated = 2016-03-12 17:34:36 +0000;
dishes = (
);
}
```

There is no dishes. But in fact they are.

What i should do ? I don't know how to get array of relations from backendless when i use a List format.

[screenshot of backendless table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N63Y6.png)

Answer (score 0):

Backendless does not return related objects on "find" request by default. This is done to decrease the size of response.

So you should either set "autoload" in your Data Console - which will change the default behaviour and always retrieve this relation, or indicate that you want to load some relations in Query Options. See the example in the docs: https://backendless.com/documentation/data/ios/data_relations_retrieve.htm

Comment: Thank you very much! it works! But now i have next problem, i see that 'dishes' containts data that was autoloaded. I can see it using 'Print description of ...' in console. I see data it looks like:  dishes = (
     "Dish {\n\tobjectId = E7 ... \tcategory = (null);\n}"
 );           but i can't get access to it , i can't print it.   I spent 3 hours and a lot of different ways to get access to this parametrs. May be you know how to get it? This type 'list' declared in Realm files. I don't know how to get data from it

Comment: i solved:)     print(categories[m].valueForKey("dishes"))           
var dishes: [Dish] = categories[m].valueForKey("dishes") as! [Dish]